# Header/Footer menu shows empty

Tags: macos, mac, headers, microsoft-word-2011

In the Documents Element menu, the header/footer and bibliography sub-menus are empty and can't select anything pre-defined from there.

Is this an issue? can I download templates for that like downloading a document template from the MS Office site?

Below is an image of the issue.

Thank you.

[image: Word 2011 Mac Document Elements menu]